Given a 3-player game and 3 utilility matrices which determine the profit of each player. Provide an algorithm to calculate nash equilibrium.
There is a 3-player game that player-1 has n actions, player-2 has m actions, and player-3 has p actions. Furthermore, 3 utilility matrices n×m, n×p, and m×p which determine the profit of each player against another are given. All matrices are zero-sum. And the utility for each players against two other players is added together. Which means that the player i's profit (i $\in \{1,2,3\}$) is equal to the sum of his profits vs the other two players.
Is there an algorithm that finds nash equilibrium in this game?

Welcome to MSE. Please try to show your work(whatever you understand, whatever you tried) and explain exactly what you need help with.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You leave a lot to your Readers' imagination.  While it isn't explicitly stated, we would surmise that $n,m,p$ are positive integers.  But the game mechanics are a matter of guessing.  Saying that "each player have[sic]" $n,m$ and $p$ actions would literally mean that players have the same "actions" available, but otherwise the overly terse statement seems to imply the first player has $n$ actions, the second player has $m$ actions, and the third player has $p$ actions to choose from.  Hence the description of three matrices for "profit of each player against another one".  Please clarify.

And how are the payoffs determined?  Is player 1's profit just equal to the sum of his profits vs the other two players?  It would be very helpful to give a nontrivial example with small $(n,m,p)$... especially one where you know the answer.

@mjqxxxx Thanks. The question was incomplete I've added more details.

Let $\psi_i$ be player $i$'s strategy, and let $M_{ij}$ be the payoff matrix for player $i$ against player $j$, such that the total payoff for player $i$ is
$$
\pi_i=\sum_{j\neq i}\psi_i^{T}\cdot M_{ij}\cdot \psi_{j}.
$$
If this is to be a Nash equilibrium, then no player can improve their payoff by slightly adjusting their strategy; that is, $\partial \pi_i / \partial \psi_i = 0$, or
$$
\sum_{j\neq i}M_{ij}\cdot \psi_j = 0
$$
(this is a vector equality).  These can be combined into one big block-matrix equation:
$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
0 & M_{21} & M_{31} \\
M_{12} & 0 & M_{32} \\
M_{13} & M_{23} & 0
\end{matrix}
\right)\left(\begin{matrix}\psi_1 \\ \psi_2 \\ \psi_3 \end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{matrix}\right).
$$
Any Nash equilibrium must be an eigenvector of the displayed matrix associated with the zero eigenvalue, and such that each $\psi_i$ is normalized (sums to unity).
